# VB.NET SQL conversion error when trying to read data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datareader

I'm trying to get data from a database but keep getting the following error.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar '102A' to data type int

The database table has 3 columns `UserID`, `UserName`, `UserInfo`, all of them defined as type `varchar`.

There is also a user in the table with ID 102A.

I'm trying to get the Username of the User with ID 10307.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim datareader As SqlDataReader

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 10307"
        datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        datareader.Read()
        MsgBox(datareader.GetValue(2))
        datareader.Close()

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I also tried to change `datareader.GetValue` to `datareader.GetString` but I get the same error.

Can anyone help me please, I've been stuck for days now...

Thank you

Comment: What line is the error thrown on? Is `Users` a table or a view? Do you get this same error when you run this command in your RDBMS? If not, can you retrieve that row there and add it to your OP? This error is indicating that you are trying to return a data type of int, however the data in that column is not able to be converted to an int because it includes letters. AS such, you need to `CAST(columnName as VARCHAR(length))` but really, you haven't given enough info to answer this question accurately.

Comment: If `UserId` is a `varchar`, the condition `... WHERE UserID = 10307` will attempt to convert all values to integers to perform the comparison. If any `UserID` values contain non-integer data, you will get a conversion error. Try changing the condition to `... WHERE UserID = '10307'` to see if it makes a difference. You can also run the query `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, UserID) IS NULL` to identify non-integer `UserID` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to use datatable. You can use that example:

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim Connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim Adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim SourceDataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim myBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder

        SourceDataSet = New DataSet()

        SourceDataSet.Reset()

        Adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = 10307", Connection)
        Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 6000

        Adapter.Fill(SourceDataSet)

        dt = SourceDataSet.Tables(0)
        dim yourValue as object = dt.rows(0).Item([your field index or field name])
```